# Separate thread from UI

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm, dispatcher

What is wrong in my program? I can not separate an executing thread from the UI. The UI can not be reached during the execution of the thread.

This is my viewmodel:

First option:

```
// on button click:
this.CreateImageList();

private void CreateImageList()
{
    this.images.Clear();

    ThreadStart threadStart = delegate
    {
        this.dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate
        {
            foreach (var filePath in this.fileBuffer)
            {
                var result = new ImageObject(filePath);
                if (result.Image != null)
                {
                    this.images.Add(result);
                    this.dispatcher.Invoke(() => this.StatusText = filePath, DispatcherPriority.Render);
                }
            }

            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Images");
        }));
    };

    var thread = new Thread(threadStart);
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();
}
```

Second option:

```
// on button click:
this.CreateImageList();

private async void CreateImageList()
{
    await this.CreateImageListAsync();
}

private async Task CreateImageListAsync()
{
    this.images.Clear();
    var countTotal = this.fileBuffer.Count();
    var index = 0;

    await Task.Run(() => this.dispatcher.Invoke(
    (() =>
    {
        foreach (var filePath in this.fileBuffer)
        {
            var result = new ImageObject(filePath);
            if (result.Image != null)
            {
                this.images.Add(result);

                var percent = (index * 100) / countTotal;
                this.DoForce(() => this.StatusText = percent + "% " + filePath);
            }

            index++;
        }

        this.RaisePropertyChanged("Images");
    }), DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle));
}

public void DoForce(Action action)
{
    this.dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, action);
}
```

In first and in second option the program do work. But In first and in second option the UI can not be reached for the User

Comment: What are the errors you get or how does the "can not be reached" actually show? Please provide an accurate fault observation, not some interpretation of what you saw!

Comment: This is because you are putting delegate on UI dispatcher itself which anyhow put it back on UI thread. You should delegate only UI tasks on UI dispatcher, rest can be run on background thread.

Comment: No errors! The program runs fine! But I can not move the window, or click any button an so on...

Comment: Rohit Vats, thank you! This is sure the solution

Comment: You shouldn't be running Threads manually. It's best to use the async/await pattern or just `Task<T>` type if you run old Visual Studio (previous to 2013) versions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are putting delegate on UI dispatcher which will anyhow run it on UI thread *(resulting in non-responsive UI)*.

You should **delegate only UI tasks on UI dispatcher**, rest can be run on background thread.

Comment: Yes, that is it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm under the impression that separate threads, whether a background or UI thread, do not have access to the main thread (except ProgressChanged). I spent a lot of time on this problem and I could not find a way to permanently access the main thread from a secondary thread.

My solution for the UI thread was using WndProc to chat between threads in concert with extended (lParam) values and/or registry values.

With the background worker thread I accessed the main thread in the progress event through a window property pointer to the main thread. You can only access the main thread from the ProgressChanged event within the BgWorker.